# laser hair reomval and varicose veins

Tags: risks, thigh, varicose-veins, laser-hair-removal

Recently, I sterted a new health program ( eating healthy +  exercising at least three times a week) . In addition to that, I bought a home laser hair removal machine, and I started using it on some specific places ( like under arms and legs). However I recognized later that I have some varicose veins in my thighs.  They are very small appearing with a dark blue color.  Despite that, I continue using my laser heair removal machine even on my thighs.

My question: Is there  any health problem of using laser hair removal on varicose veins  ? I know that varicose veins are some times trated using Laser, so what is the problem by using laser for removing hair  ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A professional hair removal laser machine doesn't purposely heat up the skin, most machines for hair removal are using a wavelength with a short burst cycle that will heat up the melanin in the hair and use the hair shaft to transfer the heat to damage the hair bulb.

A professional hair removal machine with correct settings shouldn't have any effect on varicose veins. The laser use for varicose veins treatment is more focus and powerful.

The side effect of laser removal:

- Dry skin
- Pigment changes
- Increase hair grow

http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/laser-hair-removal/basics/risks/prc-20019438

Comment: Any references ( especially for the side effects of laser removel) ?

Comment: According to Mayo Clinic's website and my personal experience http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/laser-hair-removal/basics/risks/prc-20019438